# Ringing tone after silent remote notification in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I have a silent remote notification for iOS which looks like that:

```
{
    myVar1 = myVal1;
    aps =     {
        "content-available" = 1;
    };
    myVar2 = myVal2;
}
```

which I get in:

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(nonnull NSDictionary *)myParams fetchCompletionHandler:(nonnull void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
    if ([ myParams isEqualToString:@"myVal1"])  
    //send localnotification and play sound 
}
```

Depending on myVar1 I take different actions when the application in iOS is in background mode.

What I would like to have is to be able to play a custom ringingtone sound. What I have done is the following:

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification=[[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate=[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
localNotification.alertBody=@"Some message";
localNotification.timeZone=[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.soundName=@"mySound";
localNotification.alertTitle=@"Some title";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
NSInteger numberOfBadges = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber+1;
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = numberOfBadges;



[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:numberOfBadges];
```

For localNotification.soundName=@"mySound";

I have tried the following:

```
localNotification.soundName=@"mySound.wav";
localNotification.soundName=@"mySound.m4r";
localNotification.soundName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] @"mySound.m4r"];
localNotification.soundName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] @"mySound.wav"];
```

Although I get a local notification I can't here the wav file (ringingtone), just the default alert sound of iOS.

Is there anything wrong?

Thanks

Comment: you need custom notification sound for remote notification ?

Comment: Symeon when you app is background state ios will manage the notification.

Answer (score 0):

Check, if your sound file is more than 30 seconds, then it would not play.

Are you implementing like VOIP call? then i believe you have to use PushKit.

You can maintain socket architecture, which keeps broadcasting which user if online or offline.

Even you can keep your local notification object in `NSUSderDefault`, So even your device gets restart you can retrieve `NSUSderDefault` object at `didFinishLaunchingWithOption`

When your app is about VOIP. you can use below structure to to achieve it.

Your app gets invoke in background, no matter it is in background mode or kill mode. your app will be active upto your local notification sould plays ( Max 30 seconds ).

Use below structure to achieve your task.

Use this simplepush.php file

```
<?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):


      $deviceToken = '1234567890123456789';
//


// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'ProjectName';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'My first push notification!';



$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'PemFileName.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
//  'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body

$body['aps'] = array(
                     'content-available'=> 1,
                     'alert' => $message,
                     'sound' => 'default',
                     'badge' => 0,
                     );



// Encode the payload as JSON

$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

Use below commands to create pem file and use it in above code

```
$ openssl x509 -in aps_development.cer -inform der -out PushCert.pem

# Convert .p12 to .pem. Enter your pass pharse which is the same pwd that you have given while creating the .p12 certificate. PEM pass phrase also same as .p12 cert.  
$ openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out PushKey1.pem -in pushkey.p12

Enter Import Password:

MAC verified OK

Enter PEM pass phrase:

Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:

# To remove passpharse for the key to access globally. This only solved my stream_socket_client() & certificate capath warnings.
$ openssl rsa -in PushKey1.pem -out PushKey1_Rmv.pem

Enter pass phrase for PushChatKey1.pem:

writing RSA key

# To join the two .pem file into one file:
$ cat PushCert.pem PushKey1_Rmv.pem > ApnsDev.pem
```

After that go to simplepush.php location and fire command -> php simplepush.php

This way you can test your push kit notification setup architecture.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial

[Download](https://drive.google.com/a/brainvire.com/file/d/0B7ooURy3zGWKaGxGZVV4X0Y0d3M/view)

```
import UIKit
import PushKit


class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,PKPushRegistryDelegate{



func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {


    let types: UIRemoteNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
    application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)

    self. PushKitRegistration()

    return true
}



//MARK: - PushKitRegistration

func PushKitRegistration()
{

    let mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue()
    // Create a push registry object
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {

        let voipRegistry: PKPushRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: mainQueue)

        // Set the registry's delegate to self

        voipRegistry.delegate = self

        // Set the push type to VoIP

        voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [PKPushTypeVoIP]

    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }


}


@available(iOS 8.0, *)
func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didUpdatePushCredentials credentials: PKPushCredentials!, forType type: String!) {
    // Register VoIP push token (a property of PKPushCredentials) with server

    let hexString : String = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: UnsafePointer(credentials.token.bytes),
        count: credentials.token.length).map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joinWithSeparator("")

    print(hexString)


}


@available(iOS 8.0, *)
func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload payload: PKPushPayload!, forType type: String!) {
    // Process the received push
    // From here you have to schedule your local notification

}

}
```

**Check your sound file with this configuration.**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info. The sound is actually 5sec.

I haven't used the PushKit. I'm not so sure if it will change anything. Do I use anything wrong on the notification?

Comment: By setting  "content-available" = 1; on server your notification would not be silent. I believe your app is about VOIP, right ?

Comment: Hi...yes. It's about VoIP.  In https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html in able it says:


The aps dictionary can also contain the content-available property. The content-available property with a value of 1 lets the remote notification act as a silent notification.

Comment: Just updated my answer. Please do check. Hope this worth for you.

Comment: Hi...it should be useful indeed. However I haven't used PushKit and I need to totally change the architecture now for that. Even with normal Push Notifications is it possible to play a sound through local notifications or it's not allowed?

Comment: Using normal notification and playing sound file in local notification is allowed. but it will work only when your app is in forground or background, it will not work when your app is in kill state. Local notification can not get schedule when app is in kill state. when your app goal is VOIP then using pushkit, socket, local notification is only option. by this way you can take your app to whatsapp, facebook , skype level VOIP app.

Comment: Ok...thanks. That's good news. But I'm trying to run it just in background and not when the app is killed. In local notifications in the code I'm using is there anything wrong? Because the sound doesn't really work unless it needs other configuration.

Comment: Can you try .mp3 file.

Comment: I think it's related to the path. I have tried to use [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:PathFile]) and it seems that it doesn't find the file. Is

Comment: Furthermore I see that in iOS 10 there is a change of LocalNotifications api. https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilocalnotification

Comment: Yes, there is a change for notification in iOS 10, still you have to write conditional code to support for iOS 8 and 9.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125117/discussion-between-hasya-and-symeon-mattes).